# Visual Studio 2013 intellisense without method and parameters description

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, settings, intellisense

I have this problem in my Visual Studio 2013 Express my intellisense looks like this:
[image: Attached screenshot]

At work I use professional edition where it looks like this:
[image: Attached screenshot 2]

As you can see, there is method description and info about parameters. Ofc this is only an example.

Is it limitation of express edition or I have something wrong with settings in my VS Express or I miss some components? Any ideas?

Comment: I could not answer that since I use an even higher version than both of the ones you use.. why not just create your own template or if that doesn't work.. just type in the code yourself and be on your way... is this really a `Show Stopper`...?

Comment: I can confirm that this functionality does work in Visual Studio 2013 Express. I'm trying to look into options which would disable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition(I believe it should work also for 2013):

1. Parameters are missing if your referenced dlls are unloaded or they are mismatched with architecture. Try to switch to x86 or x64 and make sure all references for that project are loaded.
2. Switch .NET framework version of your project from 4.5 to any other version and from that point you should have documentation displayed while you type code. For me documentation was available for 4, 4 Client Profile, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1.

How I found it? On fresh Windows 10 I installed **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**, then I rebooted and loaded my solution and still I had missing parameters information.

In my project properties I had .NET 4.5, then I started to switch it to 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4 Client Profile. Parameters still were missing. I had DEBUG and AnyCPU and some dlls at that time were not loaded and marked as missing because they were not AnyCPU. Then I changed it to x86 or x64 - all dlls loaded properly. After that I changed .NET versions and **parameters were missing only for 4.5! Parameters were present for all the rest of .NET versions: 4, 4 Client Profile, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1** - can you believe? I also checked all folders where dlls of .NET framework are located and in every one of them .xml documentation is present. Why it was not loaded only for .NET 4.5 and for all the rest it worked? Hm, maybe MS have a bug in installer or in VS, who knows. Anyway I changed my project .NET to 4.5.2 and I have all documentation when I type code.

Answer (score 2):

This is an option available as a customisation for C# Intellisense. However, it isn't a part of the Intellisense configuration panel, but rather the C# general configuration property.

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General. There, you should see `Parameter information` unticked. This is why you are not seeing any information when you go to enter your parameters. If you tick this, you should see them drop down once more.

[image]

Comment: I have it ticked, I also unticked it, then ticked it again. I restarted VS. Nothing. Before I asked this question I tried every combination with this settings, I also reset vs settings to default and it still doesn't work. When you untick it, you even don't have this single line from first screen - that's why I wonder about express limitation of this feature.

Comment: That's really strange, then. I'm able to reproduce what you're describing by toggling this option. What about your settings in All Languages > General?

Comment: All Languages -> General gives the same result.

Comment: In either environment, do you have/have you had Resharper installed before? I'm finding some results regarding this problem not being resolved by the above steps when Resharper is part of the equation.

Comment: As far as I know, R# does not support VS Express and I do not recall that on my current 3 months old system installation I had installed R#. On this system only VS Express.

Comment: Kind of grasping at straws, but do you have the documentation installed locally for VS2013? Maybe it's unable to show any comments because it doesn't have them installed. I'm running VS2013 Express right now though and it's working for me, though, so if you're not able to install the documentation for Express (which I think might have been a thing but I don't remember), then that isn't the problem because I wouldn't have the documentation either.